# Online database for Android studio

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, firebase

im developing an app for distributors. They will be writing data into the online database like which store bought what amount of product. So, there will be a lot of agents(distributors) and all databases should be synched. For now im using sqlite to just store data in android but its not on hosting. I watched a lot of videos and didnt find an answer for my question. Can you help me please? Now i have two choices: sqlite or firebase. I have read that sqlite is the best for android, but i dont even imagine how to put database into hosting and then set stable connection to it from my android studio project. I have never did something like this earlier. Firebase is very simple, but i knew about it yesterday, so i should learn it. But what about sqlite. I have already learned sqlite pretty well. Also after searching information i had doubtes that it 8s possible to put sqlite database on hosting. I dont have any experience, so give at least some direction or something else for the first time and tell me which database is better? And also i have a theory that mysql will be put on hosting and sqlite will be just accepting that info and converting, right? So, i will be using mysql on hosting( server ) side and sqlite on client side? Im really stupid, so please help me

Comment: Sqlite is standalone. It does not serve for shared data. Use Firestore or Firebase. It handles all the sync processes for you.

Comment: So, there is no any way with sqlite? Can't I import database data from mysql server database to sqlite? Or it will be not stable? And is Firebase and Firestore the same things? And also thank you for your fast answer)

Comment: With Sqlite you would have to handle everything yourself: sync, hosting. It would be a lot of work. And firestore and firebase are not the same. You have to choose which one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use firebase as @juergen d said. There is a lot that you can do including authentication, storage, hosting etc. And also firebase together with android have many tutorials that you can search.